# How is an anime based on western-literature made?

Tags: anime-production

I just saw some anime that are based on western literature. I was just wondering how is it done. I mean, does the anime production company have to ask permission from the author of the books? If so, what if the author has passed away? And what kind of permission do they have to take? Like some anime that are based on western-books have modifications to the real story, so do they inform the author about all the modifications? Thank you.

Comment: Removed my answer, it was pretty much the same as Dimitri's but he sent it in a bit sooner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the piece of literature is not part of the public domain, they will have to obtain the rights either at the original author or publisher, as the author may or may not hold actual rights over the product after publishing.

In the case of a deceased author whom holds the rights, it might get a little bit more complex. Considering [Dead artists can be kept alive, and make a killing](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/how-dead-authors-are-making-840289)

The actual permissions / allowed modifications are usually decided upon during the inquiring of a license. Here they can either determine that no changes are allowed, or they are free to do as they please.

Usually if somebody wishes to obtain said rights, they would hire a lawyer, as obtaining the rights, setting the terms and options, and the costs that come with it are surrounded by a lot of legal rump slump